# What signal do bg and fg send?

Tags: process, background-process, signals, jobs

I know that `ctrl` + `z` changes a process from *foreground* to *background* - as **suspended** - through `SIGTSTP`. I am able to re-run that background suspended process through either `fg` or `bg` as required.

**Question**

- What signal do `bg` and `fg` send?

Not sure if both send the same or are different.

I did realise there are no neither `man fg` nor `man bg`. And well, there is no information about the signals through `fg --help` and `bg --help`

Comment: `bg` and `fg` have not manpage. They are builtin command. running help command will show `bg` and `fg` as builtin.

Answer (score 6):

`bg` and `fg` do not send a signal. They are builtins that change how the shell behaves.

How it works is that input from the user has to reach its intended destination. When you run `bg (job)`, you're telling the shell that you don't want that process to read or write from the console anymore, just run in it.

So, from that point on, when you write to the console, the *shell* sends either the `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOU` signal to tell that process that it's not allowed to read or write, respectively.

To answer your follow-up question: when you have a process running in the foreground that you want to move to the background, you hit `Ctrl + Z` to send the `SIGTSTP` signal to the running job (which is interactive STOP signal). Then you run `bg (job #)' which tells the shell "I want this job moved to the background."

The shell will then mark that job as a background job in its memory and treat it accordingly, and send `SIGCONT` if it sees that it's currently stopped. The `bg` command doesn't itself send a signal, but the shell might send `SIGCONT` as a reaction to `bg`.

Comment: In another posts throughout StackExchange is mentioned the `SIGCONT` many times but in general. According with your answer - if none signal is not sent, how is changed/removed `SIGTSTP`?

Comment: The Foreground and Background section of the GNU C Library Reference Manual is helpful to provide some additional details: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Foreground-and-Background.html

Comment: In csh where that feature is from, the SIGCONT is sent as part of the code of the `fg`/`bg` builtins. Same in zsh.  If it's done by the shell (which runs the builtin) as part of the invocation of those builtins, it's still correct to say it's done by those builtins.

Comment: SIGTTIN/OU is not sent by the shell.